# Laravel Form Model Binding not submitting

Tags: php, forms, laravel, model

I'm having some trouble using form model binding with L4. My form is being populated, and the routes are correct but it's not submitting correctly.

Controller:

```
public function edit($id)
{
   $transaction = Transaction::where('id', '=', $id)->get();
    return View::make('transaction')->with('transactions', $transaction);

}

public function update($id)
{
    $transaction = Transaction::find($id);
    $input = Input::all();
    $transaction->status = $input['status'];
    $transaction->description = $input['description'];
    $transaction->save();
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($transactions as $transaction)
{{ Form::model($transaction, array('route' => array('transactions.update', $transaction->id))); }}
{{ Form::text('description'); }}
{{ Form::select('status', array('R' => 'Recieved', 'S' => 'Shipped', 'P' => 'Pending'), 'R'); }}
{{ Form::submit('Submit'); }}
{{ Form::close(); }} 
@endforeach
```

Comment: Are the `transactions.*` routes generated by `Route::resource()`?

Comment: How did you declare the route ? Post it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that your `transactions.*` routes are being generated via `Route::resource()`.

[Per the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#resource-controllers), Laravel generates the following routes for a resource:

```
Verb      Path                        Action  Route Name
GET       /resource                   index   resource.index
GET       /resource/create            create  resource.create
POST      /resource                   store   resource.store
GET       /resource/{resource}        show    resource.show
GET       /resource/{resource}/edit   edit    resource.edit
PUT/PATCH /resource/{resource}        update  resource.update
DELETE    /resource/{resource}        destroy resource.destroy
```

You'll see that `resource.update` is expecting a `PUT/PATCH` request, but [Laravel forms default to `POST`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form).

To fix this, add `'method' => 'PUT'` to the array of form options, like so:

```
{{ Form::model($transaction, array(
    'method' => 'PUT',
    'route'  => array('transactions.update', $transaction->id)
)); }}
```

This will add a hidden input, `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />`, to your form which tells Laravel to spoof the request as a `PUT`.